# Can I deduce one set distributive law from the other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove the distributive laws
$$A\cup (B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$
$$A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$$
I proved the first one the boring way; I would like to avoid doing the same for the second.

> Is there some clever way to deduce the second from the first?

I would guess that it is possible by using the logical contrapositive of the first statement, but I didn't quite manage to do it.

Comment: You could use de Morgan's laws, though I'm not sure if that's a circular argument or not off the top of my head. I'm inclined to say not.

Comment: Eventually, I want to do the same to the 2 de morgan laws, but I suspect it would be circular to use de morgan at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it: let $A\to A\cap B$ in the first equation. Then we get
$$(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)=((A\cap B)\cup B)\cap((A\cap B)\cup C).$$
Now $(A\cap B)\cup B)=B$. We expand $(A\cap B)\cup C=(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$ using the first equation. So we have
$$(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)=B\cap(B\cup C)\cap(A\cup C).$$
Finally, using $B\cap(B\cup C)=B$ we obtain the desired distribution law
$$(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)=B\cap(A\cup C).$$

Answer (score 2):

There's a result in [lattice theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#As_algebraic_structure) that the two distributive rules are equivalent. At this level of abstraction, we don't have any kind of complementation, so certainly no need for De Morgan.

The proof of the direction you're interested in is below... from it you can extract the algebraic properties of a lattice we use and justify them in the special case of a set algebra.

(Aside from the routine commutative and associative laws, there are the suggestively-named "absorption laws" used in the second and fifth equality.)

$$\begin{align}
(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C) &= ((A\cap B)\cup A)\cap((A\cap B)\cup C)\\&=A\cap((A\cap B)\cup C)\\&=A\cap((A\cup C)\cap (B \cup C))\\&= 
(A\cap(A\cup C))\cap (B \cup C)
\\&=  A\cap(B\cup C)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Objections : [1] It seems that the "Absorption laws" & the "Distribution laws" are Axioms in lattice theory , hence we are not proving it , we are simply assuming it. We might as well assume the Same within Set theory , without using lattice theory. [2] Even without that Objection , we still have to show that Sets & lattices correspond , which is over-kill to Prove Set theory "Distribution laws". [3] When we try to show the correspondence between Sets & lattices , we have to ensure that we are not assuming the laws we want to Prove , which might not be trivial.

Comment: @Prem The absorption laws are axioms, but the distributive laws aren't (lattices where one or equivalently both hold are called "distributive lattices"). We are showing that one distributive law implies the other law under the assumptions of commutativity, associativity and absorption. So in other words, we're reducing OP's task to proving the absorption laws in set theory.

Comment: @Prem Also, this can just be read as a "clever way to deduce the second from the first" without needing to say the word 'lattice'. One is left to justify why I could say $((A\cap B)\cup A) = A,$ etc, which is much simpler than proving a distributive law. One could complain that the overall proof is not actually that elegant, but framing it as a proof about lattices is *clarifying* not muddying things, since it shows clearly how to chunk things up logically so we don't need to worry about the potential circularities you and the comments below the post allude to.

Comment: 20 minutes ago (while taking a bath) I managed to solve the problem. I now see your comment, and see some similarity in the approach. Unfortunately, I don't really understand your answer; I have never heard of lattice theory, and am unfamiliar with the axioms.

Comment: @DavidRaveh If you're thrown off by the lattice thing, all you need to read are the equations at the bottom: they follow from one another using the first distribution law (twice) as well as a couple other basic things. Indeed your approach is pretty similar... in fact you also use both 'absorption laws' when you say $(A\cap B)\cup B) = B$ and $B\cap(B\cup C),$ and no other rules but commutativity, associativity (and the first distributive rule). (And that's all a lattice is: two operations $\cap$ and $\cup$ obeying commutativity, associativity, and the two absorption rules.)

Comment: (+1) indeed; I didn't understand what you were doing the first time I read it, but I get it now, it appears to be the same approach as mine.

Answer (score 1):

[Duality principle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualityLaw.html) may be used here.

If $\cup$ is replaced by $\cap$ and $\cap$ is replaced by $\cup$, and $\subseteq$ is replaced by $\supseteq$, then we obtain a new formula from the given formula. The duality principle says that the new formula remains true.